# WinCE 6.0 - How to show/hide programmatically the input panel?

Tags: windows-ce

I have a MFC application (dialog-based) running on a device with win ce 6.0 (ARMV41).
Do you know the API function(s) to show / hide the Software Input Panel ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`SipShowIM` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502869%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx).  There's an example [in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838341.aspx), but essentially, to show it, it looks like this:

```
SipShowIM(SIPF_ON);
```

And to hide it looks like this:

```
SipShowIM(SIPF_OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows CE you have to deal with a window named `SipWndClass`, once found you have send it the proper windows messages either to hide or show it.